# Code not returning when using websocket provider in web3

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

Below are two code snippets. I have created a 'ganache-testing.js' file and running it using `node ganache-testing.js` command

```js
Web3 = require("web3");

provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");

web3 = new Web3(provider);

getAccounts = async () => {
  console.log("Started");
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  for (const account of accounts) {
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(account);
    console.log(account, web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
  }
};

getAccounts();
```

```js
//This is the second code
Web3 = require("web3");

provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:8545");

web3 = new Web3(provider);

getAccounts = async () => {
  console.log("Started");
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  for (const account of accounts) {
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(account);
    console.log(account, web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
  }
  console.log("Completed");
};

getAccounts();
```

Both of the codes gives the same output:

```
Started
0x90e04CD9df771C31c6a81c406Bb73f871a3FBDD4 100
0x6ACabD5d20f34C19Aec6405c6956279E465FD6D8 100
0xb5068d22eb632da154A9eEC2c1940691b438F1a5 100
0x6252fe1c3e5a1B9A3eF0c0035d18FCa5b6c3f75B 100
0xafe1c27B9BAbc17BEad0F9326F03b36B4E4A2dB3 100
0x769ef23e6a1727469D75b1860E855F6708DD031a 100
0x33C35c3b96c7C3E27d0FFb38aE30ad868A08aB4A 100
0xa17493a84B10C8790A9Eb4E844BdE8154061eb03 100
0x753fa379E54D5f2DE256785F3b530f228C01b52F 100
0x22fd52A35D14AAd6552C540EE0C7663C622Df22a 100
Completed
```

However the second code does not return from execution back to the command line. Why would this be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contracts with http connections, web sockets must be closed explicitly.

For your convenience, here is a piece of code which handles both types:

```
function close() {
    if (this.web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
        this.web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
}
```